# How do I prove that $\Bbb{P}_x(\tau_1<\infty)=1$, where $\tau=\inf\{n\geq 1:X_n\neq X_0\}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, markov-chains, stopping-times

> Let $(X_n)$ be a Markov chain on a countable space $E$ and let $T$ be it's transition matrix. We assume $T(x,x)<1$ for all $x\in E$. Let $\tau=\inf\{n\geq 1:X_n\neq X_0\}$. I want to show that $\tau$ is finite $\Bbb{P}_x$ almost surely.

So my idea was to show that $\Bbb{P}_x(\tau<\infty)=1$. I thought it would be equivalent to show $\Bbb{P}_x(\tau=\infty)=0$ hence $$\begin{align} \Bbb{P}_x(\tau=\infty)&= \Bbb{P}_x(\forall x~X_n=x)\\&= \Bbb{P}_x\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 1} X_n=x\right)\\&\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\Bbb{P}_x(X_n=x)\\&=\sum_{n\geq 1}\Bbb{P}(X_n=x|X_{n-1}=x)\\&=\sum_{n\geq 1} T(x,x)\end{align}$$

But somehow this does not give me zero. Could maybe someone help me how to show this?

Comment: The second line should have an intersection, not a union

Comment: @maxjw91 ah right but then I can't do the "trick" with the sum right?

Comment: $$P_x(\tau=\infty) = P(X_1=x, X_2=x, X_3=x, \cdots \mid X_0 = x)
= \prod_{i=1}^\infty P(X_i = x \mid X_{i-1} = x)
= \prod_{i=1}^\infty T(x,x)
$$

Comment: How do you get your second equality @angryavian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for $k\in\mathbb N^*$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb P_x(\tau=k)&=&\mathbb P_x(X_0=x, X_1=x,...,X_k=x,X_{k+1}\neq x)\\
&=&\mathbb P_x\left(\bigcup_{e\in E\backslash\{x\}}X_0=x,...,X_k=x,X_{k+1}=e\right)\\
&=&\sum_{e\in E\backslash\{x\}}\mathbb P_x(X_0=x,...,X_k=x,X_{k+1}=e)\\
&=&\sum_{e\in E\backslash\{x\}}\mathbb P_x(X_0=x)T(x,x)^{k-1}T(x,e)\\
&=&T(x,x)^{k-1}\sum_{e\in E\backslash\{x\}}T(x,e)
\end{eqnarray*}
The third equality comes from the fact that $\mathbb P_x(X_0=x_0,...,X_k=x_k)=\mathbb P_x(X_0=x_0)T(x_0,x_1)...T(x_{k-1},x_k)$ by definition of a transition matrix and we also have $\mathbb P_x(X_0=x)=1$.

Now, we have :

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb P_x(\tau=\infty)&=&1-\mathbb P_x\left(\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N^*}\tau=k\right)\\
&=&1-\sum_{k\in\mathbb N^*}\mathbb P_x(\tau=k)\\
&=&1-\sum_{e\in E\backslash\{x\}}T(x,e)\sum_{k=0}^\infty T(x,x)^k\\
&=&1-(1-T(x,x))\frac{1}{1-T(x,x)}\quad\text{because $\sum_{e\in E}T(x,e)=1$}\\
&=&1-1=0
\end{eqnarray*}
and so $\tau<\infty$ $\mathbb P_x-$a.s.